# I want to randomly train 60% out of 100%, remaining 40% for testing in Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, jupyter

Here is my code, I'm wrong in logic `Xs = random.randint(1, nb_samples) #random`

```
window_size = 16 
stride = 6 
nb_samples = len(Feeding) #100%
train_ratio = 0.6 #60%

from random import randrange, uniform
import random 

Xs = random.randint(1, nb_samples) #random

X_feeding_train = [Feeding[i:i+window_size] for i in range(0, int(Xs*train_ratio), stride) if i+window_size<=int(len(Feeding))]

#X_feeding_train = [Feeding[i:i+window_size] for i in range(0, int(len(Feeding)*train_ratio), stride) if i+window_size<=int(len(Feeding))]
X_feeding_test = [Feeding[i:i+window_size] for i in range(irand, len(Feeding), stride) if i+window_size<=len(Feeding)]

X_lying_train = [Lying[i:i+window_size] for i in range(0, int(len(Lying)*train_ratio), stride) if i+window_size<=int(len(Lying))]
X_lying_test = [Lying[i:i+window_size] for i in range(int(len(Lying)*train_ratio), len(Lying), stride) if i+window_size<=len(Lying)]

X_standing_train = [Standing[i:i+window_size] for i in range(0, int(len(Standing)*train_ratio), stride) if i+window_size<=int(len(Standing))]
X_standing_test = [Standing[i:i+window_size] for i in range(int(len(Standing)*train_ratio), len(Standing), stride) if i+window_size<=len(Standing)]

X_normalw_train = [Normal_walking[i:i+window_size] for i in range(0, int(len(Normal_walking)*train_ratio), stride) if i+window_size<=int(len(Normal_walking))]
X_normalw_test = [Normal_walking[i:i+window_size] for i in range(int(len(Normal_walking)*train_ratio), len(Normal_walking), stride) if i+window_size<=len(Normal_walking)]
#add 
feedi = len(X_feeding_train) + len(X_feeding_test)


print('X_feeding_train_and_test: ', feedi)

# print('X_feeding_train: ', len(X_feeding_train))
# print('X_feeding_test: ', len(X_feeding_test))

print('X_lying_train: ', len(X_lying_train))
print('X_lying_test: ', len(X_lying_test))

print('X_standing_train: ', len(X_standing_train))
print('X_standing_test: ', len(X_standing_test))

print('X_normalw_train: ', len(X_normalw_train))
print('X_normalw_test: ', len(X_normalw_test))

print('Total: \n')
print('Train: ', len(X_feeding_train)+len(X_lying_train)+len(X_standing_train)+
     len(X_normalw_train))
print('Test: ', len(X_feeding_test)+len(X_lying_test)+len(X_standing_test)+ len(X_normalw_test))
```

And should I use `feedi = len(X_feeding_train) + len(X_feeding_test)`?
I want to randomly take 60% of training in 100%(***nb_samples = len(Feeding) #total 100%***), remaining 40% for testing
Then I want it to print the result

Answer (score 1):

you can refer: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

```
sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(*arrays, test_size=None, train_size=None, random_state=None, shuffle=True, stratify=None)[source]
```

use "numpy array" as first parameter